# How to force download a specific file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller method and it's work well , but it show the file in browser and i want to force download not show it , so what to change ?

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id, string Url)
    {
        var b = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Book_id == id);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var fileStream = client.OpenRead(b.pdf_file);
        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Comment: have you tried changing the mime type to octa stream?

Comment: @Amy that is not a good duplicate choice.

Comment: @liam Choose a better one, then.

Comment: I have..........

Comment: @liam Good teamwork.

Comment: [Go Team](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/500x/66736602/we-rock-way-to-go-team.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
return File(fileStream, "application/pdf", "MyRenamedFile.pdf");
```